# Parse char array in c

Tags: c

I am trying using C to parse this character array: "Smith C. John, 103, 10, 10, 10" (without quotes).

I already tried this:

```
int group = 0, mark1 = 0, mark2 = 0, mark3 = 0; 

char input[100];
char lastName[100];
char firstName[100];
char initial[100];
int n;

fgets(input, 1000, sourceFile);
n = sscanf(input,"%s %s. %s, %d, %d, %d, %d\n", lastName, initial, firstName, group, mark1, mark2, mark3);
```

This code reads correctly the last name and the initial (with the dot unfortunately) only.
The values should be like this:

```
lastName = Smith
initial = C
firstName = John
group = 103
mark1 = 10
mark2 = 10
mark3 = 10
```

Please help me!
Thank you!

Changed to this to work:

```
int i = 1, group = 0;
float mark1 = 0, mark2 = 0, mark3 = 0; 
char input[100];
char lastName[100];
char firstName[100];
char initial[100];
int n;

fgets(input, sizeof(input), sursa);
n = sscanf(input,"%99s %99[^'.']. %99[^','], %d, %f, %f, %f\n", lastName, initial, firstName, &group, &mark1, &mark2, &mark3);
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked for strings. Now I have problems with the decimals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass an integer pointer for `"%d"` specifier, in this case you should just take the address of the `int` variables you are passing

```
n = sscanf(input,
           "%s %s. %s, %d, %d, %d, %d\n", 
           lastName, 
           initial, 
           firstName, 
           &group, 
        /* ^ pass the address of group */
           &mark1, 
           &mark2, 
           &mark3
);
```

If you had compiler warnings enabled, it would have warned you of that.

Also, you declare input

```
char input[100];
```

and then call `fgets()` like this

```
fgets(input, 1000, sourceFile);
```

that could overflow input, to prevent that you can use the `sizeof` operator

```
fgets(input, sizeof(input), sourceFile);
```

note that, the `sizeof` operator does not compute the length of the string in the `input` array, but rather the array size in bytes.

To find the length of a string you need the `strlen()` function.

You should also change the format string to

```
"%99s%99[^'.'].%99[^','],%d,%d,%d,%d\n"
```

here the `%99` prevents a buffer overflow, and it should be 1 less than the size of the buffer *"1 for the terminating `'\0'`"*, the `"%99[^'.']"` means consume all characters except `'.'` so it stops when a `'.'` is found then, explicitly consume the `'.'`, `"%99[^',']"` same explanation as the `'.'` but for the `','`.

So the resulting code would be

```
n = sscanf(input,
           "%99s%99[^'.'].%99[^','],%d,%d,%d,%d\n", 
           lastName, 
           initial, 
           firstName, 
           &group, 
        /* ^ pass the address of group */
           &mark1, 
           &mark2, 
           &mark3
);
```

Comment: Thank you again! I changed the code considering what you said.